# Browser Side vs Client Side data transfer

Tags: apex, javascript, actionfunction, status

I have a question on basic browser-server functionality. I am trying to get my JS to see my apex variable `resStatusCode` which is set to the webservice's res code.

```
public static Integer resStatusCode {get;set;}
...
resStatusCode = res.getStatusCode();
```

I have an actionFunction:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="refreshBankData" action="{!bankDataButton}" reRender="form" status="spinnerStatus1" oncomplete="closeWindow();"/>
```

and a JS function:

```
function closeWindow() {
    console.log('res: ' + '{!resStatusCode}');
    if({!resStatusCode} == 200){
        alert('Success - Your Bank Data Has Been Refreshed');
        setTimeout(function(){
            self.close();
        },1000);
    }
}
```

My JS is unable to view the `resStatusCode` because (I assume) that the apex code has not yet come to the browser side. The value is still stuck on the back end. How would I be able to pull the value to the browser without having to do a refresh? Could anyone explain what is going on here with data storage?

My variable has to be static because I am using @RemoteAction with my webcallout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key point from the [apex:actionFunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) documentation is:

> apex:actionFunction defines a new JavaScript function which can then
>   be called from within a block of JavaScript code

so you need to call the automatically generated JavaScript function `refreshBankData` somewhere. (Presumably you are.)

To pick up new values from the controller using Visualforce's `{! ... }` expression, the controller property cannot be static, and the part of the page that has the `{! ... }` expression needs to be within the part of the page that is re-rendered (as the new value is returned in the replacement HTML returned by the Ajax call).

Comment: you are right, I needed to have the JS in the section that I was reRendering so it would pick up the new value. The only thing is that the static variable is working as is so I don't need to change that. All is working now. Thank you!